# Interpreting Mongostat and Mongotop output

Tags: mongodb, profiling

I'm doing some profiling on mongodb using `mongostat` and `mongotop`

I run mongotop:

```
$> mongotop 30
```

and mongostat simply:

```
$> mongostat
```

The outputs are:

Mongotop:

```
                    ns       total        read       write      2012-11-23T01:32:37
           sapi.Socket      1222ms      1222ms         0ms
       sapi.ChargeSpot       999ms       999ms         0ms
```

Mongostat:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults          locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn     set repl       time 
     0   5351      0      0       0       1       0   608m  3.67g    64m      0          sapi:0.0%          0       0|0     1|0   569k     1m    63 capi-rs  PRI   12:32:41 
     0   4189      0      0       0       1       0   608m  3.67g    64m      0 knightsbridge:0.0%          0       0|0     0|0   499k   308k    63 capi-rs  PRI   12:32:42
```

Questions:

- For the mongotop output, since I ran it to report on 30 second
  intervals, does e.g. sapi.Socket total of 1222ms reads mean that:

  in the 30 second interval, 1222ms is spent executing read queries
  from the collection sapi.Socket

  Which would mean that in the 30 seconds, mongo was only busy for
  2,221ms (1,222ms + 999ms) handling read queries, in other words,
  mongo was idle for the other 27 seconds?
- For mongostat output, It looks like mongo is handling around 5K queries
  per second, is this pushing mongo a bit or is mongo capable of much
  more? the queries are basic (lookup up by indexed key)

Comment: looking at mongostat you are not pushing this mongo instance at all. On a different server or with different data the limits might be very different.

Comment: So is my interpretation correct? that mongo was busy querying or 3 seconds, and idle for the other 27 seconds?

Comment: @Dzhu, +1 to what Asya Kamsky said: the Mongo database used at my workplace typically gets around > 12,000 queries per second.  I wouldn't start worrying unless you start seeing around 15K queries regularly.

Answer (score 2):

All of the operations per second metrics are going to be a relative metric per your particular server's config and the cluster architecture. You are not pushing Mongo with 5k queries however.

A complimentary tool to use is the DB profiler. The profiler will capture all ops in this case to a system collection named system.profile. You can then gleam some more insights into individual queries and how they are performing.

//example of diagnostics for just query operations, not inserts or deletes or commands, against a //DB named dfl and a collection named test.

db.system.profile.find({op: {$eq : 'query'}, ns: 'dfl.test'})

//check your profiler status
db.getProfilingStatus()

//set the profiler to all operations
db.setProfilingLevel(2)

Answer (score 0):

For performance tuning, we have seen `explain`, `hint` and `profile` options. But what if we want to look at the high level inside a program and figure out where it's spending it's time, how would we do that? We've `Mongotop`, named after `Unix` command `top`. To see the log on the shell use command `mongotop seconds` - where `seconds` is the number of seconds after which the next log entry shall be printed.

e.g.: `mongotop 3`